# using jquery.getJson with Google's GeoCoding HTTP Service

Tags: jquery, geocoding, getjson

Google offers a wonderful REST interface for geocoding and reverse geocoding an address. My API key is valid, and if I enter the request directly into the browser address it works great. However, the following jquery fails terrible and I'm failing to see why. Hoping you could help me out here.

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+ address+"&key="+apiKey+"&sensor=false&output=json",
  function(data, textStatus){
     console.log(data);
  });
```

Google's REST interface doc for this service: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that I wasn't specifying the JSONP callback. The correct code is as follows

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+ address+"&key="+apiKey+"&sensor=false&output=json&callback=?",
  function(data, textStatus){
     console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: It's working because you specify yourself the `callback` parameter at the end of the query but if you let jQuery handle it (by specifying `dataType: 'jsonp'`) it won't, please see: http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/03/fix-jquery-jsonp-request-to-google-maps.html

Answer (score 3):

Due to security restrictions, you can not send an AJAX request to a URL from a page in a different domain.  That is why it works if you enter the URL in the browser, but not if you try to make the request from your javascript code.

A common workaround is to use a [server side component acting as a proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html): it receives your AJAX requests and sends them to the google geolocator.

Comment: According to JQuery's website, $.getJSON has native support for JSONP request. Thus, there should be no need for said Proxy

Comment: No problem as long as the remote URL you're calling supports JSONP.  Google has disabled JSONP for V3 of the GeoCoding API being mentioned above.

Comment: JSONP is a work around to the XSS security built into browsers, this actually started out as a security loophole but is now so widely used I don't see them ever fixing it.

Comment: @Gabe: They didn't disabled it, just secured it even more (than v2) :)

Answer (score 0):

add an error function

```
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Ajax Error: " + xhr.status + "\nMsg: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
```

and try to debug if it is just a json related error

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same trouble.  This is how I was able to ultimately get it to work for me.

[see google maps api docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding)