# Global location input autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, geolocation, geocoding

I was looking for a plugin to create a smart location form field which has a suggested autocomplete. I was unable to find anything suitable (Google Geocode is too unreliable on its own, and it isn't designed for this) so I built my own. I thought it was crazy that in 2011 an open-source global location input plugin like this didn't exist so set out to give it a go.

The demo is here http://labs.unxposed.net/unxposed/geocode/ and is working on Chrome and Firefox 4. Download is here https://github.com/unxposed/geocode

There is one major issue I am having with it. Sometimes it works great like so. On typing **Ban** in the input I get a list of suggestions back. The input is autofilled with the first suggestion back matching **Ban** and the input text after **Ban** is selected (much like the Chrome address bar).

[image]

However, much of the time the autofill selected text in the input becomes unhighlighted and the cursor then moves to the end of the input (which is really annoying). Like so - after I type **Banbur**.

[image]

I am pretty sure this is related to Google Maps as if I remove the secondary source (Google Geocode) the issue is resolved and autofill/input select works great consistently, but why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Any other improvements/optimisations/suggestions would be greatly appreciated too!

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a difference on your pics and on demo it works fine for me on chrome, sometimes using ajax it can glitch and it might take a few seconds to return data after the request.

Comment: The first image the input has been autofilled and the text after **Ban** highlighted. On the second image the input has been autofilled correctly but the text after **Banbur** (the text I input) has not been highlighted, as it should have been. Or rather it may have been highlighted but then it is unhighlighted automatically right after - like if the right arrow key has been pressed.

Comment: that happens on ban as well it just takes a little longer

Comment: Yep, it can happen on anything. It seems arbitary. Sometimes it's fine, but most of the time the highlight doesn't stay highlighted for whatever reason. That's the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't want it highlighted either, and that is kinda annoying when you try and delete the whole thing, it wont let you select and clear the input field, if I was a user on a website, and not able to do something (n if i was an middle aged and computer illeterate)  I would just navigate away from your website

Comment: It works like the Chrome address bar. I think they know a thing or two about usability. I really like how it works.

Answer (score 0):

What is your data source of locations? If it is geonames.org, they have different geographies on different servers - with different performance characteristics.  Hence it is common on a worldwide search to see jerks, odd responses, etc. as different servers toss back at different times. I found that user selection of a country, and feeding that into the city query pretty much eliminates jerkiness, odd responses, etc. If you are using geonames.org, they require attribution at the search box.  If you are using a google data source of names, I can't comment, but you might check how they handle major versus minor countries.  Also, think about the level of detail provided.  Geonames is remarkable on that score.

Answer (score 0):

There **is** a widget that does that, the jquery ui autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

This demo is exactly what you need, selecting locations over the world

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: By smart location I mean something that can also handle input of postcodes, street addresses etc. Autocomplete alone doesn't also doesn't map the location.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is related to the highlighting you might want to check the success section of your ajax call and make sure that you are un-highlighting in the right moment. Because the section is always changing it might glitch at one point given the nature of bringing back lots of info and altering dynamically

hope this helps!

ps. autocomplete jQuery will autocomplete anything it feeds from

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one
Download http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/
Demo : http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html

Comment: While this link may theoreticaly answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

OSClass.org provides its theme for free which has location autocomplete with all areas being populated automatically. This you can check in their demo and download the code from within their theme files.
Demo (login and go to Settings->location section) : http://demo.osclass.org/general/oc-admin/index.php?page=login