# JQuery Googlemap V3 Geocoding with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have implemented this using php, but I wanted to change it to use JQuery on the client's side.
What I am trying to do is get the data from the JSON file recieved from Googlemaps and use it to save the latitude and longitude to my database, however I have been unable to even get the data into variables.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#test").append('STUFF HERE');

    var geocodeURL = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=92408&sensor=false';

    $.getJSON(geocodeURL, function(data){

            var latitude = data.results.geometry.location.lat;
            var longitude = data.results.geometry.location.lng;

            alert(longitude);

            $("#test").append('<p>'+latitude +'</p><p>'+longitude+'</p>');

    });

});

</script>

<div id="test" ></div>
```

When I paste the GeocodeURL into the browser I get the following return:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "92408",
               "short_name" : "92408",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "San Bernardino",
               "short_name" : "San Bernardino",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "San Bernardino",
               "short_name" : "San Bernardino",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "San Bernardino, CA 92408, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.10665490,
                  "lng" : -117.208780
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.0501660,
                  "lng" : -117.3071210
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.08685170,
               "lng" : -117.26173290
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.10665490,
                  "lng" : -117.208780
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.0501660,
                  "lng" : -117.3071210
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

After a day or two or researching and tweaking I haven't been able to find out what's wrong, and I'm hoping that this is an easy question for someone who's already been there and done that, cause I've been stuck..

------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------

So as far as I can tell, there's no way to do Google Map's JSON with the above method, and instead you must use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"

    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">

</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address= '92408';

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            var TEST = results[0].geometry.location;
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            alert(TEST);
            alert(longitude);
            } 
        else 
        {
                result = "Unable to find address: " + status;
            }
    });


});

</script>

<div id="test" ></div>
```

Now the problem is getting the actual latitude and longitude from the .location portion of the returned JSON file.
When the ' alert(TEST); ' is run, the following is output:

```
(34.0868517, -117.26173289999997)
```

This is the correct long/lat pair, but when I try to put the individual longitude or latitude I get the following output: (from alert(longitude))

```
function () {
    return this[a];
}
```

Any ideas anyone?

-----------------------------------------Solved------------------------------------

Ok, it was a simple solution..
Change :

```
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

to:

```
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: the url u are equesting from is different the the docs: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
is an example url from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I found this thread which might help:
[using jquery.getJson with Google's GeoCoding HTTP Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898201/using-jquery-getjson-with-googles-geocoding-http-service)
Has to do with not providing the call back function