# Google Maps V3 Geocoding Lookup using getJSON

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, getjson

I have a question similar to here:

[using jquery.getJson with Google's GeoCoding HTTP Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898201/using-jquery-getjson-with-googles-geocoding-http-service)

with the exception that I'm trying to retrieve the geo-coordinates for an address without using the API key, from a client-side lookup.

Everything seems to work when using this code:

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=202++3991+Henning+Dr+Burnaby+BC+V5C+6N5&sensor=false&callback=?",
  function(data, textStatus){
     console.log(data);
     console.log(textStatus);
});
```

However, I'm getting an 'invalid label' jQuery error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use this method instead of just using the JavaScript Maps API Geocoder? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V3 geocoding API doesn't support  the callback parameter, so the JSONP call you're trying to make won't work.  Instead you could use the JavaScript API and use the [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) or proxy the results through your web server (to get around the cross-site issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the web service directly because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Lucky, there is a solution: The [Geocoding Service in the Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).