# Google Maps URL doesn't return the JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Kfc+sydney&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyD-jxenRCJipqw5Kg-HXQbRXUK8dHNFz3A',
    function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

My Google Maps URL shows the JSON object when requesting it from the browser but not from using jQuery.

Comment: The Google Maps API does not seem to allow cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Places-Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of the Maps-Javascript-API to request the service from a javascript-application.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false">
</script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'))
     .textSearch({query:'KFC sydney'}, function(data){console.log(data);});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay more attention to your browser's JS console.

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Kfc+sydney&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyD-jxenRCJipqw5Kg-HXQbRXUK8dHNFz3A. Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

You are trying to violate the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Some work arounds are described in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: @user2082934 — No, there isn't "some piece of code" that will solve the problem. Read the links.

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Google Maps V3 Geocoding Lookup using getJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216073/google-maps-v3-geocoding-lookup-using-getjson?lq=1)

***FYI*** - if you are running a server-side language, such as PHP or JSP, you will be able to use the maps api url, as there are no javascript cross-domain issues with that approach, and you could write a page to effectively act as a proxy if you need to use javascript for handling the JSON.